# When to use MVVM (i.e. Knockout.js) or simply return an EditorTemplate object from Controller action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, mvvm, knockout.js, mvc-editor-templates

In cases where new items need to be added to a list via ajax, what is the biggest benefit of using something like Knockout.

So far what I have been doing is, on my view, use an editortemplate (with asscociated viewmodels) to render a list of items. Then to add a new item, I make a request to an action that loads a server-side viewmodel, and returns an EditorTemplte object which just gets appended to the list. Like this:

```
return Json(new { this.RenderPartialViewToString("MyEditorTemplate", model) });
```

The knockout way of doing things requires the implementation of another view model to display items, and then another template to display it.  But doing it this way requires duplication of code since the view model has to be represented in 2 places: in the cserver side code and then the view for the knockout viewmodel. Isn't that bad practice?

Am I missing something, or understanding the purpose of knockout and MVVM?

Answer (score 2):

The biggest benefit that you will see from Knockout is that you *will not* need to hit the server in order to add a new item to your list - everything happens client side. This has multiple benefits including:

- You reduce load on your server.
- You improve the end-user's experience.
- You can keep multiple elements on the page up-to-date with your model without any server interactions.

Two great examples of this can be found at these Knockout tutorials:

- [Working with Lists and Collections](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=collections)
- [Loading and Saving Data](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=loadingsaving)

As far as duplicating code, if you take a look at those two tutorials, you'll notice that you don't need to duplicate code. For example:

1. Create a view to display your entire list.
2. To add a new item to the list, create a partial view that you load when you add a new item to the page - that partial view is bound to Knockout
3. When you submit the entire form, everything in that list will be submitted - including those items you added via Knockout.

Your ViewModel will be specific to your list item (you don't need to create an entire ViewModel for everything, necessarily). And your view is specific to a single list item.

Hope that's clear. Knockout is pretty straightforward and they have some great documentation and tutorials to help you move forward.

Comment: Thank, you.  Those examples are helpful. I guess there is no way around having to do some mapping when going from server side to client side (like when the example uses the $.map function). And I understand how this fits together, but is it a reasonable concern to worry about what happens when the server-side definition changes? It would break all the mappings on any view that it was used.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "server-side definition changes." Typical approach is: send your data to your view (from the server), map to the objects using Knockout (either manually or using Knockout Mapper), the user makes whatever updates (all done client), send the data back to your server so that you can persist the changes, display the next view || Is there something you're trying to do in addition?

Comment: what I mean by "server-side definition changes" is say my server view model gets a property added to it, then I would also have to update any screen where knockout maps from that viewmodel.

Comment: @getit - Ah, yes. That may be true depending on how you use KO. However, one thing about KO is that you don't necessarily need to keep KO's VM 100% in sync with what you have on your server. For example, maybe you only use KO to affect a single, dynamic list. Just because you add other items to your main VM doesn't mean you even need to touch KO. A lot of that is in how you design your solution. It's not necessarily a straight 1-to-1.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, the following is cleanest option for the architecture of knockout and asp mvc mixed together.

Have your ASP.net acting as a webservice and have knockout control all your view templating and logic.

Otherwise, yes there will be potential replication of viewmodels and having to refactor both front and backend code when you need to change your model.